# Are colon and equals treated the same in http headers?

Tags: http-headers

In the following example both colon (:) and equals (=) are used to send http headers.

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

Are they interchangable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not. In fact,

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

means that `Content-Type` has the value

```
text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I.e., there's no `charset` field in your header.